# Spring Boot different data.sql files for different h2 tests

Tags: java, spring, h2

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=Application.class)
public class TaskProviderTest {
}
```

I'm using h2 database configured in property file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=PostgreSQL
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

And I'm using schema.sql and data.sql files for unit tests. Both scripts are executed on test startup.

Is there anyway to use different data.sql files for different Junit test cases ?

Comment: How are you loading data.sql currently ? I mean can you add the code ?

Comment: It is added automatically somehow by spring-boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use EmbeddedDataSource and configure it from method in code.
The code below is demonstrates how to create datasource with 2 sql scripts

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();

    return builder
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
            .addScript("sql/create-db.sql")
            .addScript("sql/fill-db.sql")
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring's `EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder` to construct the database in the `setUp()` method of your unit tests, providing different `data.sql` scripts for different tests.

Example:

```
public EmbeddedDatabase database(String dataScript) {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().
            setType(H2).
            addScript("schema.sql").
            addScript(dataScript).
            build();
}
```

Reference:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder.html